# Python Pandas Delete From Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to write a script to scrub information from csvs. I have a pandas df created from a csv like below:

```
CUSTOMER ORDERS
  hashed_customer      firstname    lastname    email   order_id    status          timestamp
0      eater 1_uuid  1_firstname  1_lastname  1_email    12345    OPTED_IN     2020-05-14 20:45:15
1      eater 2_uuid  2_firstname  2_lastname  2_email    23456    OPTED_IN     2020-05-14 20:29:22
2      eater 3_uuid  3_firstname  3_lastname  3_email    34567    OPTED_IN     2020-05-14 19:31:55
3      eater 4_uuid  4_firstname  4_lastname  4_email    45678    OPTED_IN     2020-05-14 17:49:27
4      eater 5_uuid  5_firstname  5_lastname  5_email    56789    OPTED_IN     2020-05-14 16:22:33
```

I have another csv with the hashed_customers that I need to scrub from this file. So if the hashed_customer in this file is in CUSTOMER ORDERS, I need to remove the firstname, lastname, and email from the row while keeping the rest, to look something like this:

```
CUSTOMER ORDERS
      hashed_customer      firstname    lastname    email   order_id    status          timestamp
    0      eater 1_uuid         NULL        NULL     NULL    12345    OPTED_IN     2020-05-14 20:45:15
    1      eater 2_uuid  2_firstname  2_lastname  2_email    23456    OPTED_IN     2020-05-14 20:29:22
    2      eater 3_uuid  3_firstname  3_lastname  3_email    34567    OPTED_IN     2020-05-14 19:31:55
    3      eater 4_uuid         NULL        NULL     NULL    45678    OPTED_IN     2020-05-14 17:49:27
    4      eater 5_uuid  5_firstname  5_lastname  5_email    56789    OPTED_IN     2020-05-14 16:22:33
```

My current script looks like this:

```
print('FIND ORDERS FROM OPT-OUT CUSTOMERS')
cust_opt_out_order = []
for index, row in df_in.iterrows():
    if row.hashed_eater_uuid in cust_opt_out_id:
        cust_opt_out_order.append(row.order_id)

print('REMOVE OPT-OUT FROM OPT-IN FILE')
df_cust_out = df_in[~df_in['hashed_eater_uuid'].isin(cust_opt_out_id)]
```

But this is removing the entire row, and now I need to keep the row and only remove the name and email elements from the row. How can I drop elements from a row using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do

```
df_cust_out = df_in.copy()
df_cust_out.loc[df_in['hashed_eater_uuid'].isin(cust_opt_out_id),['firstname','lastname', 'email']]=np.nan
```

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you so much!